why is the object sent from angular to my .net controller null after it gets to controller? and how to fix it?
This is .Net Core 3.1 and Angular 9
The payload shows the correct object, but its null when it gets to controller. I tried checking all the properties they all seem to match. what should i try differently?
//angular function
getData(forwArray: number[], gac: string, sort: string, isGroupby: boolean, isFCCode: boolean): Observable<any> {
 
//edited per suggestion
 const requestData:ClientInfoRequestModel ={
  forwarders:forwArray,
  gac:gac,
  sort:sort,
  isGroupby:isGroupby,
  isFCCode:isFCCode,
}

  //removed per suggestion
  //const httpOptions = {
  //  headers: new HttpHeaders({
  //    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  //  })
  //};
  console.log('requestData=', requestData);
  return this.http.post(this._ClientInfoURL, requestData ,httpOptions);
}

//c# controller
//I removed [FromBody] below and can now see the object, but the values of each property are either null or default to false
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult GetClientInfo([FromBody] ClientInfoRequestModel requestData)
{
//requestData is an object but values of each property are null or default ... why?  and how to fix?
}

//c# class
 public class ClientInfoRequestModel
 {
     public int[] forwarders { get; set; }
     public string gac { get; set; }
     public bool isGroupby { get; set; }
     public bool isFCCode { get; set; }
     public string sort { get; set; }
 }

//edited the angular class to an interface
export interface ClientInfoRequestModel {
  public forwarders: number[] = [];
  public isGroupby: boolean;
  public isFCCode: boolean;
  public gac: string;
  public sort: string;
}

MORE INFO.  Here are more things I tried.
in the .ts service , added this
console.log('requestData=', requestData);

in the dev tools console here is the object
requestData= {forwarders: Array(152), gac: 'TA', sort: '', isGroupby: false, isFCCode: true}
In the Network tab, here is the Payload

forwarders
: 
[3845, 3847, 3992, …]
gac
: 
"TA"
isFCCode
: 
true
isGroupby
: 
false
sort
: 
""

In the .Net Core 3.1 Controller
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetClientInfo(ClientInfoRequestModel requestData)
//the requestData object has all null or default values

Also, just tried adding this instead of the previous Controller method.
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetClientInfo()
 {

//var requestForm = await Request.Form.ReadAsStringAsync();//no definition for ReadAsStringAsync
 var form = await Request.ReadFormAsync();  
//the code executed this line but it never makes it to next line  
 var requestBody = form.ToString(); 
}


as is that shouldn't build.  You'd need to initialize all those fields in your export class ClientInfoRequestModel.  If you do that, though, it should work.  The constructor isn't needed there, or the httpOptions object, but neither should prevent the model from binding.  I would check to be sure the endpoint is hit by putting a breakpoint there.  Also check the request payload in the browser's inspector just to be sure it matches the server-side model.  (not sure if the const might be the issue?  That should be ClientInfoRequestModel instead, but I don't think that'd cause a problem either.)

Posting more complete versions of your code may help.  Also passing in ClientInfoRequestModel to the getData() method in angular should help troubleshoot.  (easier than passing in all the fields separately too)

Your passing formArray?, it's not formarray.value?
NOTE: To check, try define your controller like (after check remove the code
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetClientInfo()
{
    var requestBody = await Request.Body.ReadAsStringAsync();
    //check the value, should be a json string, 
    //but you can see the name of the properties
    return Ok($"Request Body As String: {requestBody}");
}

I think that you have a problem with PascalCase and CamelCase variables
NOTE 2: If you have a "class" that have no method, In Angular it's better use a simple interface
//better
export interface ClientInfoRequestModel {
  public forwarders: number[] = [];
  public isGroupby: boolean;
  public isFCCode: boolean;
  public gac: string;
  public sort: string;
}

You can use simple
const requestData:ClientInfoRequestModel ={
  forwarders:forwArray,
  gac:gac,
  sort:sort,
  isGroupby:isGroupby,
  isFCCode:isFCCode,
}

NOTE 3: Angular by defect send the variables as json, so you can remove the httpOptions
return this.http.post(this._ClientInfoURL, requestData);


not sure about formArray? vs formarray.value?

i tried changing the Controller method as you suggested .. your exact code did not work, but the following returned an empty string "var requestBody = await new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();"

I edited the angular class to an interface, no effect

i too, thought it would be a CamelCase vs PascalCase, but can not find that issue

@greg, try request.Form instead of request.Body

tried it, no definition, tried similar,  added notes in my question above
